# How to print upto 100th decimal places accurately of a float or double type variable?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, floating-accuracy

Suppose there are two numbers 22 and 7. I want to print up to the 100th decimal place of the answer which should look like 3.1428571428571428571428571.... whereas trying to use

```
cout << setprecision(100) << fixed << (22.0/7.0);
```

I get something like 3.142857142857142793701541449991054832935333251953125.......

Comment: neither `float` nor `double` have that many significant figures when when converted into decimal notation. [Specifically, `float` has roughly 7 decimal digits of precision, and `double` has 16.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation)

Comment: You probably want to try a library like gmp.

Comment: Don't confuse precision (how many decimal places you can show) with accuracy (how many of those decimal places are correct.)  Once you are past the fifteenth significant digit you might as well just append random digits.

Comment: @ jaggedSpire I added one answer. I do not know how to put it here in comments in better format.  So I put there. I am getting  SEG violation.  My question is can we some how put the entire content in a stream?

Comment: Also to put things in context: to measure the diameter of the solar system (4.5 * 10^12 m) in units of proton radii (~10 ^ -15 m) would take 28 significant digits. Even if you could represent a number to 100 significant places it not quite clear why you would want to (other than as an exercise in meaningless busy work.)

Comment: Appreciate your thinking @Dale Wilson

Comment: @DaleWilson: Despite your context, some applications require BigDecimals with many more than 28 significant digits, even if their values far exceed the approximate number of atoms in the known universe (somewhere between 10^80 and 10^85, IIRC).

Comment: Not in C++ (in Delphi and assembler, actually), but I wrote a simple library that uses BigIntegers (also in my library) to display the exact value represented by a float or double. But you probably need BigDecimals. These can have a much higher precision and a precision of 100 is no problem at all. Unfortunately, I don't know a nice library for C++. As @JamesKPolk already said, you can use the C and assembler (for many platforms) based gmp (GNU Multi-Precision) library (gmplib), although it is a little awkward to use, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally in c++, the double (the bigger of the two) is stored in 8 bytes.
that's means that the number can contain 2^8*8 = 2^64 byes (^ = power).
that's means the biggest number of digits after the point, after keeping the sign and the floating point location, would be at most ~15 digits. therefore you will have to create other means then double for this calculation.
here is my reference:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm

Answer (score 0):

When I try

```
int main()
{
   const long double pi = 22.0/7.0;
   std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::max()) << pi << '\n';
}
```

I am getting segmentation leak.

The max you get is:

```
int main()
{
    const long double pi = 22.0/7.0;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits) <<   pi << '\n';
}
```

output is:
3.142857142857142793701541449991054832935333251953125

Comment: What do you expect from the first example? `std::numeric_limits<long double>::max()` is the largest number representable by `long double` (not the number of significant digits) and you are implicitly casting it to `int` which is undefined behavior because the value cannot be represented as an `int`. `std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits` is the number of base-2 digits representable, not decimal digits. You will output many more digits than are significant.

Comment: But I have another question basically. I put in question comments. I will put it here too.  
I am getting SEG violation. My question is can we some how put the entire content in a stream? –

Comment: `digits10` is also wrong, it is the number of base-10 digits that can be represented without change. It is lower than the accuracy of the stored value. Since C++11 there is `max_digits10` which will give you the number of significant digits needed to store any value of the type uniquely. Of course the exponent needs to be saved additionally, i.e. via scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

The printing is not the problem.  Code is well printing the quotient *as a double*.

```
cout << setprecision(100) << fixed << (22.0/7.0);

OP's reported result
3.142857142857142793701541449991054832935333251953125.......
// My expected result of the double 22.0/7.0
3.1428571428571427937015414499910548329353332519531250000000....
```

---

Using `double` math, in general, will not provide OP with 100 digit accuracy.  Here is why.

**Different explanation approach**

A `double` is typically 64-bits.  That gives up to 2<sup>64</sup> combinations of *exactly representable* numbers.   Consider `double n,d,q;` and dividing `n/d`.  That is 2<sup>128</sup> different combinations of `n,d` yet we are trying to put all those results in `q`.  Many will result in the same answer (22.0/11.0 and 14.0/7.0 both make 2.0).  Yet there are certainly more than 2<sup>64</sup> different mathematical answers.

So C *rounds* the answer to the best - typically closest - *representable* `double`.

In this case: 22.0/7.0, exactly, in not one of those 2<sup>64</sup> combinations.
The "best" is "something like 3.142857 142857 142793 7015414..."

```
double x = 22.0/7.0;
//  x   3.142857 142857 142793 701...

// 22.0/7.0
// math 3.142857 142857 142857 142857 

double next_x = nextafter(22.0/7.0, 4.0);
//      3.142857 142857 143237 790...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this to get the answer rounded off upto 100 decimal points.

```
    double long a,b,n;
    cin>>a>>b;
    n=a/b;
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(100);
    std::cout << n << '\n';
```